# How to insert multivalued field into one column in hive

Tags: hive

I have csv file of format
(id,name,courses)
and data is like
1,"ABC","C,C++,DS"
2,"DEF","Java"

How to load such type of data in hive?

Answer (score 0):

First, create a table

```
hive>create table tablename(text STRING, count INT) ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',';
```

Then load data to hive:

```
hive>LOAD DATA INPATH '/hdfspath' OVERWRITE INTO TABLE tablename;
```